# Dual monitors and OS X Lion : get menubar and app switcher on both displays

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I've just plugged in another monitor into my 13 inch MBP running OS X Lion.

It works fine, except for three little annoyances:

- Whenever I use the application switcher (or whatever it's called, I mean the thing that appears when you use <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>), it appears only on the MBP screen. I also want it on the external screen I attached.
- same problem with the top menu bar. It only appears on the MBP screen, but I also want to see it on the external screen.
- and again, same problem for the dock.

Is there a way to fix these three things?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They can't appear on both screens. You can, however, have it swap to being on the external screen when the external screen is attached, by selecting "Arrangement" and just dragging the 'little grey bar' (not sure how else to describe it) onto the external screen. This also moves the quick switcher onto the big screen.

I have exactly the same setup as you - and the same annoyances - to solve mine I elevated my screen put the MBP underneath it - then I can have my menubar and switcher on the MBP and the apps themselves on the big screen.

Comment: thanks for the tip with the grey bar, I guess that works

Comment: "They can't appear on both screens." Damnit, Apple. Why not? http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: This answer is not accurate for newer versions of macOS, see @Jesus Adolfo Rodriguez's answer below

Comment: This answer is now out of date. See Jesus Rodriguez's answer

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is a way to do this natively. (without downloading third party software)

```
Preferences > Mission Control
```

tick the box that says "Displays have separate spaces"

Then you will have to log out and log in back again to see the menu bar on both displays

[image]

Comment: The problem when you do that, is that you have no more the Menu Bar in secondary displays; only in Main Display. So annoying

Comment: Another problem with this setting is that apps like Citrix can't use both displays for full screen mode: https://helpcenter.steinberg.de/hc/en-us/articles/206693470-Mac-How-to-span-windows-across-multiple-displays

Answer (score 6):

Try [SecondBar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33264/secondbar) and [Dock Spaces](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27841/dock-spaces).  I haven't gotten around to trying either yet but together they satisfy your request for the menu bar and dock though not the app switcher.